# Calculate variance with VB.NET lambda expression

Tags: vb.net, linq, lambda

I am trying to convert the following code for the **variance calculation**

```
public static double Variance(this IEnumerable<double> source) 
{ 
    double avg = source.Average();
    double d = source.Aggregate(0.0, 
                 (total, next) => total += Math.Pow(next - avg, 2)); 
    return d / (source.Count() - 1);
}
```

described on [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/linq/LinqStatistics.aspx) into corresponded VB.NET lambda expression syntax, but I am stuck in the conversion of **Aggregate** function.

How can I implement that code in VB.NET?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following will only work in VB 10. Prior versions didn’t support multi-line lambdas.

```
Dim d = source.Aggregate(0.0,
    Function(total, next)
        total += (next - avg) ^ 2
        Return total
    End Function)
```

`Function(foo) bar` corresponds to the single-statement lambda `(foo) => bar` in C# but you need the multi-line lambda here which only exists since VB 10.

However, I’m wary of the original code. Modifying `total` seems like an error, since no `Aggregate` overload passes its arguments by reference. So I’m suggesting that the original code is wrong (even though it may actually compile), and that the correct solution (in VB) would look like this:

```
Dim d = source.Aggregate(0.0, _
    Function(total, next) total + (next - avg) ^ 2)
```

Furthermore, this doesn’t require any multi-line lambdas, and thus also works on older versions of VB.

Comment: Well, `total += whatever` will return the new value of `total`, so it will *work*, it's just misleading because it does the same thing as `total + whatever` - setting `total` to a new value in the lambda does nothing.

Comment: @BlueRaja: that’s what I meant.